# Implementing rot13 in python

Tags: python, rot13

I am trying to implement the rot13 algorithm. Obviously not hard but my issue is with strings that have an apostrophe in python I don't know what to do to fix this. I am not sure if the issue is with my program or with the way python runs because I tried running an empty program like so "python3 solve.py ' " and it didn't run but gives me a > in the terminal.
I'll also add my code below if anyone sees something else wrong.
By empty program, I just call a main that does nothing.

```
import sys


def main(input):
    output = ""
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ABC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    for i in input:
        if ord(i) in range(65,91):
            output += ABC[((ABC.find(i) + 13) % 26)]
        elif ord(i) in range(97,123):
            output += abc[((abc.find(i) + 13) % 26)]
        else:
            output += i
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = main(sys.argv[1])

    print(result)
```

Comment: Your program looks correct. The issue is that in most shells `'` indicates the start of a literal. In windows you can do `py -3 solve.py "'"` (this is 2 double quotes enclosing a single quote). There will be different escape mechanisms depending on the shell you use.

Comment: Are you literally running `python3 solve.py '` at the command-line?  That has nothing to do with Python.  That has to do with your shell, which is waiting for you to continue entering text until it reaches a closing quote.  Your question is about how to escape a single quote in your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single apostrophe serves as a start of quoted, possibly multiline, string and that is the reason for the `>` prompt you see. Too send a single apostrophe you can either escape it or quote it with double quotes:

```
$ python solve.py \'
'
$ python solve.py "'"
'
```